# Juntar 2 tipos de busqueda

Tags: php, mysql

necesito hacer que me haga una busqueda por status y otra por palabra clave, pero solo puede hacer un tipo de busqueda, no puede hacer los 2, estoy atorado, alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
Este es mi codigo

```
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] != NULL) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'ajax') {
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_REQUEST['query'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $status_r = intval($_REQUEST['status_bus']);
    $tables = "interesado";
    $order = "ORDER BY correo DESC";
    $campos = "*";
    $sWhere = "id LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR nombre LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR estado LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR ciudad LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR telefono LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR correo LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR vacante LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR tienda LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR fuente LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";
    if (!empty($query)) {
        $sWhere .= " OR id LIKE '%" . $query . "%'";
    }
    if (!empty($status_r)) {
        $sWhere .= " OR status LIKE '%" . $status_r . "%'";
    }
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
    $per_page = intval($_REQUEST['per_page']); //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $tables WHERE $sWhere");
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)) {
        $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows / $per_page);
    $reload = './permisos.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $campos FROM $tables WHERE $sWhere $order LIMIT $offset,$per_page");
    //loop through fetched data
```

Esta es la busqueda por palabras
[image: Busqueda por palabras]
Y esta por status
[image: Busqueda por status]
Lo que me gustaria es que hiciera los 2 tipos de busqueda pero solamente puede hacer uno, los intente juntar con un if pero no funciono

Comment: No logro entender bien, ¿necesitas hacer una búsqueda en dos campos de la tabla?

Comment: Necesito hacer que se pueda hacer 2 tipos de busqueda y la default

Comment: Quieres que se cumpla el criterio de búsqueda ¿ **Y** u **O** ? el estatus seleccionado

Comment: que  se pudiera buscar por palabras clave mientras estoy buscando por status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logre hacer la solucion pensando en que cada proceso es uno diferente metiendolo en 3 if
uno donde busque por status otro por palabra y otro donde no se hace una de las 2 busquedas

```
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] != NULL) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'ajax') {
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_REQUEST['query'], ENT_QUOTES)));
    $status_r = intval($_REQUEST['status_bus']);
    $tables = "interesado";
    $order = "ORDER BY correo DESC";
    $campos = "*";
    if (!empty($query) && empty($status_r) ) {  //Busqueda por palabras clave
        $sWhere = "id LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR nombre LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR estado LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR ciudad LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR telefono LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR correo LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR vacante LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR tienda LIKE '%" . $query . "%' OR fuente LIKE '%" . $query . "%' ";
    }
    if (!empty($status_r) && empty($query)) { //Busqueda por status
        $sWhere = "status LIKE '%" . $status_r . "%'";
    }
    if(empty($status_r) && empty($query)){//Sin seleccion de busqueda
        $sWhere =" id LIKE id";
    }
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page'])) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;
    $per_page = intval($_REQUEST['per_page']); //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $tables WHERE $sWhere");
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)) {
        $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows / $per_page);
    $reload = './permisos.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT $campos FROM $tables WHERE $sWhere $order LIMIT $offset,$per_page");
    //loop through fetched data
```